# Twilio Test Credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, twilio, credentials

I'm trying to use my test credentials to make a call from my browser, and a js error is always raising before making any call:

```
 Object { message="No valid account",  code=31203}
```

I put my test credentials everywhere and I used my app_sid to generate a token using Twilio Capability like this: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby#getting-started-with-client-capability-tokens

I was able to use this app with production credentials, but not for test.

What is missing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid the test credentials don't cover using the API for Twilio Client applications. In fact, the test credentials are very limited and best used for  testing failures from the Twilio API. Please see this article on the [Twilio Test Credentials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials) for the full details.

Comment: Here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials#test-calls I can see making calls... I guess it is from server-side, but just guessing. It is like this? So there is no way to use test-credentials from my client?

Comment: I'm afraid not, you can't create capability tokens with test credentials. You need to use production credentials I'm afraid.